# I am just getting a promise, no response with Axios

Tags: node.js, axios

I am trying to transalte some php code to nodejs/javascript

[image]

I am a noob with nodejs and Axios I dont know if I am doing it right. But I thought it could work with the following code

```
exports.getCheckOutId = async (amount ) => {

  const data = {
    'authentication.userId' : userId,
    'authentication.password' : password,
    'authentication.entityId' : entityId,
    'amount' : amount,
    'paymentType' : paymentType,
    'currency' : currency
  };

  return await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: host + path,
    data: data,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  });
};
```

When I try to check what is going on

```
const response = getCheckOutId(5).then(result => console.log("after then: ", result) );
console.log(response);
```

I just get

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

I am no able to see the response

I tried with an without rejectUnauthorized: false just in case ssl was the problem.
I also tried this approach but I am not able to see any of my console logs nor an error.

```
axios.post(url, data, axiosConfig).
  then((response) => {
    console.log('accessed successfully');
    return response;
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
    return null;
  })
```

Comment: Where do you define host, path, currency and paymentType?

Comment: @Josh it is global for now, I did check with console.log for those variables and they do show up inside my function

Comment: The clue is what you’re seeing in the repsone where it say promise pending.  You need to resolve or reject a promise.  Promise pending means your call has not finished before you’re trying to check it. In your last code snippet replace return response with resolve(response).  Similarly, replace return null with reject(err).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't catching your error, so it isn't showing you what is wrong. Try this:

```
exports.getCheckOutId = async amount => {
  const data = {
    'authentication.userId': userId,
    'authentication.password': password,
    'authentication.entityId': entityId,
    amount: amount,
    paymentType: paymentType,
    currency: currency,
  };

  try {
    const result = await axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: host + path,
      data,
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    });
    console.log('result: ', result);
    return result;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
};
```

Comment: i need to do another await when calling my function